# How can I iterate through a CSV file and plot it to a boxplot by each column representing a second in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, boxplot

Say I have a csv file like so:

```
20  30  33  54  12  56
90  54  66  12  88  11
33  22  63  86  12  65
11  44  65  34  23  26
```

I want to create a boxplot where each column is a second, which is also the x-axis. The actual data to be on the y. So, 20, 90, 33, 11 will be on 1 second and on one plot and 30, 54, 22, 44 on 2 seconds and so on. Also, the csv file has more data than this that I am not sure how many data sets so I can't hard code anything in.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/user/Desktop/test.csv', header = None)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('ms')

df.boxplot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want a separate plot for each second, or all seconds on one plot?

Comment: @MasonCaiby 10 per each graph since there are so many data sets. so every 10 seconds is on a different graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
axes = df.groupby(df.columns//10, axis=1).boxplot(subplots=True, 
                                           figsize=(12,18))

plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('ms')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to set `y` limits of the subplots:

```
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.set_ylim(0,100)
```

Comment: With this I get "ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length"

Comment: On line: df.groupby(df.columns // 10).boxplot(ax = ax)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Two questions. What does "axis = 1" do? And do you know how I can limit the y axis on the plots? I tried plt.ylim=(0, 100) but that didn't work

Comment: this isn't working, what am i doing wrong? axes = df.groupby(ylim = (0, 100))